# Creating Layouts for selected windows in MapInfo

Tags: mapinfo, layouts

I have a workspace from which I need to create a lot of different layouts, which need to be kept. Each time I create a layout which has five windows (2 of which are the same, copyright and key), I then minimize them all and open a new map window for the next site.

When I then open a new layout window for all currently open windows, every window appears in the layout and I have to delete all but the ones that I need.

Is there a way of specifying which ones I want to be included each time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new blank window from the Windows menu.

Use the frame tool to draw a rectangle on the Layout.  Use the drop down in the dialog box to specify the map window that you want to appear on the Layout.

Draw a frame for other items you want to add such as a legend, other map windows, etc.